# Jasperreport - send list of objects from Java application

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a Java class with two attribute id (integer) and name (string). I have created a list of objects and I want to use the *JasperReports* to make a pdf file.

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(conceptsList,true);
Map jasperParameters = new HashMap();       
jasperParameters.put("Concepts", ds);
String input = "C:/report.jasper";
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(input, jasperParameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp, "C:/report.pdf");
```

In iReport Designer I have one parameter (Concepts) and set *net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource* as a parameter class. I also define two fields id and name and put them in the details band. but my pdf file does not show anything. I think somewhere I have to define datasource for id and name but I cannot find anything. It would be great if anyone can help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report22" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="313d6b25-bcea-43a0-80db-2c7733499ca2">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="Concepts" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
<title>
    <band height="50" splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<detail>
    <band height="200" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="b6c2dc20-ebaa-4dfe-8d42-b8318bf05d33"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="fbc83087-e178-4210-a9f0-a8e1d86a5f71"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: Why you are passing datasource as parameter? Why you are using the empty datasource? You should post the *jrxml* file

Comment: Alex I want to send more than one list of objects to make a complex report. Because of that I pass my datasource  as parameter and use an empty datasource. I have done it before but unfortunately I can't remember how.

Comment: Ok. Can you show the *jrxml* file?

Comment: I put my XML file. Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the object data as a datasource to JRXML. Additionally, if the List should also be sent as a datasource to JRXML.

First design the iReport to accept Object as datasource:
1) Add the project "src" in class-path in iReport.
2) Specify the object package.className in JRXML report datasource.
3) Map the TextFields with the Object parameters.

Now in source code, use "JRBeanCollectionDataSource" Class for sending the List of Object in "JasperFillManager.fillReport()", for Connection.

Hope this helps.